# How do I translate series of lat, lon coordinates to x,y coordinates by giving example sets of matches to train/study

Tags: python, coordinates, geocode

I have a 3d model imported for a certain city scene.
The 3d model has x,y coordinates based on the view.

However, I don't have lat/lon coordinates of the buildings in the scene.

Using python, is there a way to translate real world lat/lon to x,y coordinates
in the scene that I have by having a series of lat/lon to x,y samples to be referenced.

For example,
I would like to tell

1.There are hundreds of building in the scene. Identify  all the lat/lon of the each building in the scene.

2. I have a few samples to be referenced.
   In the map,
   (x1,y1) is (30.232,40.232)
   (x2,y2) is (40.232,50.556)
   (x3,y3) is (55.245,67.594)
   ...
   (x10,y10) is (34.535,62.563)

using these 10 references, try to figure out all the buildings' lat/lon.

What would be a way to achieve this ideally python?

Comment: Converting x,y(,z) coordinates to lat, lon is tricky.  Mostly because The Earth is not a sphere and geodesics are difficult.

There's a tool out there called [pyproj](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/examples.html) that'll do some of what you ask, but I don't know the library well enough to answer your question.